# In what order Lookup transformation loads data from multiple Excel sheets in SSIS?

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

I created a package that uses Lookup transformation to loop through multiple Excel spreadsheet and loading data into SQL.

**The question is**: If excel spreadsheets are not ordered in a source folder then in what order Lookup transformation will be looping through each of the sheet?
Based on last modified date? based on name in alphabetical order?

The spreadsheets have a different dates, does it meant it loads data in order based on a date?

[image]

Comment: I don't know how what you describe is even possible.   Please show some screenshots of how you have set up this Lookup.

Comment: I modified the question. Basically I have a folder with 15 excel sheets. How (in which order) lookup transformation will go through each of them when loading data to sql?

Comment: Your edit didn't help, let me be more clear.   It is only possible to use an OLEDB source in a Lookup Transformation.   An OLEDB source, to my knowledge, cannot "loop through multiple Excel spreadsheets".  So your question says you are doing something that is impossible, so you are probably not accurately describing what you are doing.  Can you post either a screenshot, or step-by-step description of HOW you set up this lookup transformation?

Comment: Did you mean a for each loop container? *(not lookup transformation)*

Comment: is it a lookup transformation or for each loop container ?

Comment: As per your question "Lookup transformation will be looping through each of the sheet?". Lookup transformation will not loop through each sheet, it can lookup your master data set with the reference data and if matches do thingA if not do thingB.